# Regex Get result if found and if not get another result

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the max resolution from m3u8 file.

Here's the sample m3u8 content:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=149000,RESOLUTION=320x180,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://URL/index_0_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBuNs5OuBzaVwrmOF+jXvWJ+HkjL%2fShsITuRsvq00%2f+IYwrOKyjWNrak9RN+Vq0bDNLLJZ47ZVL1w%3d%3d&hdntl=exp=1597650826~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=9a46c5ffe594c611b03e0dfbd8e5981aab024fae8492abc40f0fcd7c854af59a
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=298000,RESOLUTION=320x180,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://URL/index_1_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBuNs5OuBzaVwrmOF+jXvWJ+HkjL%2fShsITuRsvq00%2f+IYwrOKyjWNrak9RN+Vq0bDNLLJZ47ZVL1w%3d%3d&hdntl=exp=1597650826~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=9a46c5ffe594c611b03e0dfbd8e5981aab024fae8492abc40f0fcd7c854af59a
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=499000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.64001f, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://URL/index_2_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBuNs5OuBzaVwrmOF+jXvWJ+HkjL%2fShsITuRsvq00%2f+IYwrOKyjWNrak9RN+Vq0bDNLLJZ47ZVL1w%3d%3d&hdntl=exp=1597650826~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=9a46c5ffe594c611b03e0dfbd8e5981aab024fae8492abc40f0fcd7c854af59a
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=800000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.64001f, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://URL/index_3_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBuNs5OuBzaVwrmOF+jXvWJ+HkjL%2fShsITuRsvq00%2f+IYwrOKyjWNrak9RN+Vq0bDNLLJZ47ZVL1w%3d%3d&hdntl=exp=1597650826~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=9a46c5ffe594c611b03e0dfbd8e5981aab024fae8492abc40f0fcd7c854af59a
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1062000,RESOLUTION=960x540,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://URL/index_4_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBuNs5OuBzaVwrmOF+jXvWJ+HkjL%2fShsITuRsvq00%2f+IYwrOKyjWNrak9RN+Vq0bDNLLJZ47ZVL1w%3d%3d&hdntl=exp=1597650826~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=9a46c5ffe594c611b03e0dfbd8e5981aab024fae8492abc40f0fcd7c854af59a
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1361000,RESOLUTION=960x540,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://URL/index_5_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBuNs5OuBzaVwrmOF+jXvWJ+HkjL%2fShsITuRsvq00%2f+IYwrOKyjWNrak9RN+Vq0bDNLLJZ47ZVL1w%3d%3d&hdntl=exp=1597650826~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=9a46c5ffe594c611b03e0dfbd8e5981aab024fae8492abc40f0fcd7c854af59a
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1503000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001f, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://URL/index_6_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBuNs5OuBzaVwrmOF+jXvWJ+HkjL%2fShsITuRsvq00%2f+IYwrOKyjWNrak9RN+Vq0bDNLLJZ47ZVL1w%3d%3d&hdntl=exp=1597650826~acl=%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=9a46c5ffe594c611b03e0dfbd8e5981aab024fae8492abc40f0fcd7c854af59a
```

I'm using this regex to get the maximum resolution which is the last URL "https://URL/index_6_av.m3u8?".

```
(https.*\w*index_6\w*.*)"
```

My question is, if the "index_6 which is 720p" is not found, how I can get the "index_5" instead so that the result is not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^https.*index_\d+.*\Z
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/paaTJb/1)**.

What's changed:

- Replaced the `6` with `\d+` which will match one or more digits.
- Added `\Z` (i.e., [End of String Anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)) at the end to only match the very last occurrence.
- The capturing group is redundant so it was removed.
- The two `\w*` also seem redundant (because they're either followed or preceded by `.*`). You may add more restrictions if you need them.

---

Note: The solution above will only work if the indices are in ascending order. It's mentioned in the question that it should match the last URL so I'm assuming they *are* in order. If that's not the case, you could write something like this instead:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"^https.*index_(\d{1,9}).*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    var targetMatch = matches
                      .OfType<Match>()
                      .OrderByDescending(m => int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value))
                      .First();
    string targetUrl = targetMatch.Value;
}
```